# Comparing two XML files in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to find a fairly easy way to compare two XML files in C#.
I need the output of this comparison to be:

- what is the difference in XML structure (including inner children and so on).
- what is the difference in the values(for example: 1 and 2 will count as a difference).

I also need the ability to disregard certain changes in value.
For example, the comparison will receive a number of values that their value is irrelevant.

Thanks in advance!
Hadar

Answer (score 6):

Comparing XML documents is non-trivial. Since you're using .NET you might want to take a look at the [XML Diff and Patch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx) stuff from Microsoft (the page contains some code examples).

The libraries generate a "diffgram" – an XML representation of the delta between two documents, and you may need to perform further operations on this to zero-in on the changes you are interested in.